# PriorityBlockingQueue blocks too long

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using a `PriorityBlockingQueue` to store tf-idf scores for features. Since this part is multithreaded I am using a `synchronized` block to take care of concurrency:

```
long ticAdd = 0;
long tocAdd = 0;
long ticPoll = 0;
long tocPoll = 0;
long ticAll = System.nanoTime();

PriorityBlockingQueue<TfIdfScore> allScores = sharedFeatureNameToScores.get(featureName);

// ..

synchronized (allScores) {  

    ticAdd = System.nanoTime();
    allScores.add(instanceScore);
    tocAdd = System.nanoTime();

    int allScoresSize = allScores.size();

    ticPoll = System.nanoTime();
    while( allScoresSize > scoresToKeepCount) {                 
        allScores.poll();                               
        allScoresSize = allScores.size();
    }
    tocPoll = System.nanoTime();

    long tocAll = System.nanoTime();

    if( ((tocAll - ticAll) /(1e6)) > 10 ) {
        System.out.println("---\nallScores.size " + allScores.size());
        System.out.println("add duration: " + ((tocAdd - ticAdd) /(1e6)) + "ms");
        System.out.println("poll duration: " + ((tocPoll - ticPoll) /(1e6)) + "ms");
        System.out.println("overall duration: " + ((tocAll - ticAll) /(1e6)) + "ms");               
    }
} // end synchronized
```

The problem is that this seems to block for a quite long time sometimes and I just can't find out why this is the case. The queue isn't very large or anything but as you can see in my output it is blocking rather long (sometimes):

```
---
allScores.size 471
add duration: 3.34E-4ms
poll duration: 12.02297ms
overall duration: 12.023402ms
---
allScores.size 471
add duration: 3988.91183ms            <===
poll duration: 0.002303ms
overall duration: 3988.915091ms
--
allScores.size 471
add duration: 4.69E-4ms
poll duration: 4002.275955ms          <===
overall duration: 4002.276525ms
```

Why is this happening? You can imagine that this slows down my program quite a bit ..

Another thing that is strange is that sometimes the *add* part and sometimes the *poll* part takes longer.

Comment: _Since this part is multithreaded..._  How many threads?  What are they doing?

Comment: _The queue isn't very large..._  How large is it?  It has almost five hundred elements when the routine is finished, but how many did it have at the start?

Comment: Where is `allScores` declared?  Is it a static variable in some class?  Is it an instance method?  If so, Is one instance shared by more than one thread?  How about those `ticXxxxxx` and `tocXxxxxx` variables?  Static? or instance?  If instance, are they shared?

Comment: @jameslarge At the moment I am using 7 threads. Well they are calculating scores for features from documents but independently form each other. The only point where the threads collide are these lines codes up there I posted. I can't find an explanation why they block so long ..

Comment: @jameslarge The log reveals the size: 471 elements here. `allScores` is a `PriorityBlockingQueue` (see code) that is shared with the other threads (not static). `ticX` and `tocX` are just local `long` variables.

Comment: The log reveals that the size is 471 elements _after_ the loop has called `allScores.poll()`  some number of times.  The loop appeared to take four seconds to run in some cases, How many items did it pop off the queue during that time?

Comment: If ticAdd and friends are local variables in some method, then why don't you show us the whole method?  The question revolves around a queue that is shared by seven threads.  Have you shown us _all_ of the places where items can be added to the queue?  have you shown us all of the places where items are popped off?   As it is, you have not shown enough of your code for anybody to be able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @jameslarge There are no further places where a score-list from a feature gets accessed. If you take a look at the code you see that a `TfIdfScore` gets added to the queue and right after the adding one element gets polled. So the maximum of elements that get polled is just 1 - always. `instanceScore` gets created a few lines before the `synchronized` block. It gets inserted and the last element of the queue gets removed. That's it.

Comment: Most likely, something external to your process is causing the delay (in which case nobody here will be able to help you) or some part of the code that you have hidden from us does not do what you think it does (in which case, nobody here will be able to help you).  If you want us to believe that a single iteration of that loop takes four seconds to complete when the queue holds 472 items and no other thread is touching it, then you will have to back that claim up by posting a complete program, that anybody can run, that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend removing the synchronization on the object monitor instead ask you to depend on synchronization using ConcurrentLinkedQueue wrapping or using synchronizedCollection(Collection c).

This might reduce the blocking latency while using generic object locking.

Comment: Will be the first thing I try as soon as I'm back on the machine where I have access to the project.